# Chinese CC adjustable load microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, load

I've bought recently [a cheap adjustable load from AliExpress](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/ATORCH-150W-Constant-Current-Electronic-Load-200V20A-Battery-Tester-Discharge-Capacity-Tester-meter-12V24V48V-Lead-acid/32821877897.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.15.66325a3e25nqPW&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_5_10152_10151_10065_10344_10068_5722815_10342_10343_10340_5722915_10341_5722615_10696_10084_10083_10618_10305_10304_10307_10306_10302_5722715_5711215_10059_308_100031_10103_10624_10623_10622_5711315_5722515_10621_10620,searchweb201603_55,ppcSwitch_5&algo_expid=29a793fd-2e04-408c-b568-5a0147158836-2&algo_pvid=29a793fd-2e04-408c-b568-5a0147158836&priceBeautifyAB=0) (see link).

For the price, it's really decent. I use if to test LiPo batteries discharge.

All in all, I'm really happy with it, but it really, really lacks at least one feature: data exporting. It would be perfect is I could extract the datas from its little brain.

Upon some researches, I was pretty disappointed to find that its main microcontroller is a rebranded (is it really?) chip referenced as "00RBJ03" for which absolutely no datasheet can be found. However, the chip right next to it is a simple 64kb EEPROM, for storing values I guess.

Have you ever encountered this kind of problem? Is there anything I can do to get to know what is that microcontroller?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: You might want to record what it's writing to the EEPROM. Whether you can make sense of that is another matter... Probably easier to buy a cheap cell capacity meter from the same source. I have one; it works (even though my load is a simple resistor).

Comment: Parts with no numbers or impossible-to-find numbers are unfortunately common in cheap no-name equipment like that.

Comment: There's not much you could do with the information even if you had the part number. The firmware will be locked and unless you want to re-invent everything from scratch (in which case use whatever micro you are familiar with and prepare for a lot of work). There are a few popular families- you may be able to suss it out from the power pins, but after that you have a dead end.

Comment: 24c320 is actually 4kx8bits eeprom

Comment: maybe the micro-controller has a uart output that mirrors the display content?  else you may need to sniff the stream to the display.